# How to not change the swiper slide position after closing the modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal, swiper.js

I've tried to combine the swiper slide and modal and set the slidesPerView is 3. However, I found out that the slide will go to the first slide position after I close the modal of the second or third slide. Is there any way to keep the slide position after the modal is closed?

[Here is my demo](https://codepen.io/TinaChiu/pen/yLxZZRw)
The swiper version is 8.0.6

I've tried to add this to the js, but it still changes the position.

`$('.modal .btn-close').on('click', function() { var activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex; swiper.slideTo(activeIndex, 0, false); });`

Comment: We're facing the exact same issue, not quite sure what is going on here. Were you able to fix this? We're using Ionic 7.x and Swiper 10.x

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to fix it. At the end, I used Swiper 7.x and it worked well.

Comment: Yikes, we really don't want to downgrade. Weird that this bug still exists in 10.x. We'll open an issue on GitHub.